# Story about a boy stranded on a remote island off Australia who trains dolphins

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

I'm looking for a book where the basic story points are:

1. A young boy lives near a hovercraft track in Australia. One day he finds that one is broken near his house and hops in.
2. The ship is broken to pieces in the middle of the ocean and the guy is left alone in the sea
3. A group of dolphins pushes him to a remote island
4. He gets used to the life in the island and trains some dolphins to work with humans
5. After some time, a disaster hits the island and some prominent figure gets hurt badly and the communications are lost.
6. The boy swims to the Australian shore with the help of a board and dolphins to get help for the injured person.

Comment: ^_^ Glad I could help. I just happened to hit the right set of keywords in Google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds a bit like Arthur C. Clarke's [*Dolphin Island*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin_Island_(novel)).

[image: Book cover]

> Late one night (in the world of the future), a giant cargo **hovership** makes an emergency landing somewhere in the middle of the United States and an enterprising **teenager** named Johnny Clinton stows away on it. A few hours later, the **craft crashes** into the Pacific Ocean. The crew ("even the ship's cat") is offloaded onto lifeboats, leaving Johnny (who, as a stowaway, was not on the ship's manifest) adrift in the flotsam from the wreckage. **His life is saved by the "People of the Sea"—dolphins**. A school of these fantastic creatures guides him to an island on **Australia's** Great Barrier Reef. Johnny becomes involved with the work of a strange and fascinating research community where a brilliant professor tries to communicate with dolphins. Johnny learns skindiving and survives a typhoon—only to risk his life again, immediately afterwards, to **get medical help** for the people on the island.